# Prevent Screen Capture in Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, mobile, plugins, xamarin.ios, screenshot

I want to prevent sensitive information from capturing in ios xamarin project.

I've got this plugin, but instead of implementing it as a whole, if I want to just use the iOS screen protection code.
As the Xamarin project is not updated and not compatible with maui plugin,

https://github.com/FabriBertani/Plugin.Maui.ScreenSecurity/blob/main/Plugin.Maui.ScreenSecurity/Platforms/iOS/Protections/ScreenshotProtectionManager.cs

what would be the process to follow?

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use a Plugin I suggest using this one,

https://github.com/FabriBertani/Plugin.Maui.ScreenSecurity

It is really simple to use as well, just create an object and use the correct methods in Appearing and Disappearing. Also read the disclaimer on this plugin so you know what are the limitations

Add the using:

```
using Plugin.Maui.ScreenSecurity;

public Ctor()
{
   screenSecurity= ScreenSecurity.Default;
}

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    screenSecurity.ActivateScreenSecurityProtection();
}

protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    screenSecurity.DeactivateScreenSecurityProtection();
    base.OnDisappearing();
}
```

Let me know if you have queries

Comment: I'm not looking to use the plugin directly but to just use the ios implementation of this plugin by creating a dependency service.

Comment: I need help in converting the plugins ios code used for screen security to xamarin.

Comment: Its open go to github and get the code you need